# How to configure SFTP Outbound Gateway using Java Config?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I would like to use the SFTP Outbound Gateway to `get` a file via SFTP but I only find examples using XML config. How can this be done using Java config?

**Update** (Thanks to Artem Bilan help)

MyConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        sftpSessionFactory.setHost("myhost");
        sftpSessionFactory.setPort(22);
        sftpSessionFactory.setUser("uname");
        sftpSessionFactory.setPassword("pass");
        sftpSessionFactory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(sftpSessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new  SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "get", "#getPayload() == '/home/samadmin/test.endf'");
        sftpOutboundGateway.setLocalDirectory(new File("C:/test/gateway/"));
        return sftpOutboundGateway;
    }

}
```

My application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
public class TestIntegrationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestIntegrationApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Configuration succeeds now but no SFTP occurs. Need to figure out how to request SFTP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/sftp.html#_configuring_with_java_configuration_20):

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    return new SftpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory(), "ls");
}
```

Also pay attention to the Java DSL sample in the next section there.

**EDIT**

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new  SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "get", "payload");
    sftpOutboundGateway.setLocalDirectory(new File("C:/test/gateway/"));
    return sftpOutboundGateway;
}
```

In case of `GET` SFTP command the `expression` ctor arg maybe like above - just a reference to the `Message.getPayload()` for all incoming messages.

In this case you should send to the `sftpChannel` a `Message` like:

```
new GenericMessage<>("/home/samadmin/test.endf");
```

So, that `/home/samadmin/test.endf` is a `payload` of that `Message`. When it arrives to the `SftpOutboundGateway`, that expression is evaluated against that message and `getPayload()` is called by SpEL. So, the `GET` command will be preformed with the desired path to the remote file.

An other message may have fully different path to some other file.

Comment: Is Java config for SFTP Outbound Gateway available in version 4.3.1? In the current GA (4.3.1), I was unable find a constructor with parameters supporting `new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "ls")` where `sftpSessionFactory` is of type `SessionFactory<LsEntry>`

Comment: Well, we have a bug in that doc. Agree. But that is a sample, some template anyway. You should choose an appropriate constructor for your use-case. I guess that should be like `SftpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory(), "get", "'THE_PATH_TO_REMOTE_FILE'")`.

Comment: I'm receiving `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1070E:(pos 0): Problem parsing left operand` when trying to create the `MessageHandler` bean. I have two beans in my `@Configuration` class: the `MessageHandler` and `SessionFactory<LsEntry>`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing to share your code. The third ctor parameter is an `expression` to determine the remote path. In case of `LS` it is directory. For `GET` the path with file. That path can be determined against `requestMessage`, e.g. you can specify remote path in the `headers`. From here that expression can be like `headers['my_remote_file_path']`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/spel.html

Comment: Your expression `headers['/home/uname/test.txt']` looks strange. Feels like that `'/home/uname/test.txt'` is exactly a path to your file. For a simple use-case I'd suggest to use `expression = "payload"`, where `payload` of the request message on the `sftpChannel` is exactly a path to remote file.

Comment: You're right. The path is to a specific file. I'm not sure where to specify `expression = "payload"`. The `SftpOutboundGateway` constructor I used in the above code requires an expression `String` argument. If I pass `"expression = \"/home/samadmin/test.endf\""` for that argument, the file is not downloaded. The above code is my entire application configuration. Am I missing something?

Comment: M-m-m. You missing that `expression` in my comment is a ctor arg name. The `payload` is exactly SpEL expression which will be evaluated against each incoming `Message` as a root evaluation context object. In this case the `payload` really means `getPayload()` on the `Message` object.

Comment: Sorry. I still can't figure this out. Code added above.

Comment: Please, find an EDIT in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help and thanks to you and other contributors for the great work on the Spring Integration project.